# Converting Pandas Series to categorical encodings

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, and I'm trying to encode all the categorical values within the dataframe. So the following is the code I wrote to encode all categorical columns in one go,

```py
for col in data.select_dtypes('object').columns:
        data[col] = data[col].astype('category').cat.codes
```

but this works only sometimes and often throws the following error saying "Dataframe has no attributed as cat"

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cat'`

Now I'm not able to understand how it works sometimes and fails other times. Also I haven't applied the cat method to the whole dataframe but to a column (series) each time going though the loop.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is there are duplicated columns names, so if select one column get all columns with same label.

```
for col in data.select_dtypes('object').columns:
    print (col)
    #check what select
    print (data[col] )
    data[col] = data[col].astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: I just checked and all column names are unique.

Comment: @AmanSingh - So what is column name if error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cat'` ?

Comment: I found it, its because the column name was with square brackets. Column name "[ emp job title ]" may be that's why Pandas was recognising it as dataframe and not series. Well, thanks for the help Jezrael